# Help me understand the answers

Tags: geometry, rectangles

*THE PROBLEM*

Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle and $E, F$ the means of the sides $AB$, respectively $AD.$ We know that there is a point $M$ on the segment $AC$ such that $\angle EMF = 60$ and  $AC^2 = 4*ME*MF$ .  Show that ABCD is square.

**My idea**

*drawing*

[image]

Okey, so the first thing i thought of is that drawing the heights $MX$ and $MY$ are going to help us.

What about writing the area of traingle $FEM$ as $ME**MF*\sqrt{3}/4$

Idk how the $AC^2 = 4*ME*MF$ ia going to help us.

If we show some congruences of angles and triangles in the rectangle $AXMF$ the problem is solved.

Comment: Huh?  `a**b` usually means $a^b$

Comment: Anyway. a small hint: $AC=2EF$.

Comment: Worst title ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all boils down to showing that $EMF$ is equilateral. To this aim, let $G$ a point such that $GF \cong EM$, and $\angle GFE \cong \angle EFM$.

Since $2EF \cong  AC$, from $AC^2 \cong 4\cdot EM \cdot MF$ you get $EF^2 \cong EM\cdot MF$, i.e. $$EF:ME = MF:EF,$$ which means that $EMF \sim GEF$ (SAS criterion). In particular, $\angle GEF \cong \angle EFM$, since they are opposed to proportional sides. Hence the two triangles are isosceles. Since $\measuredangle EMF = 60^\circ$, we have, in fact, that they are equilateral.

**EDIT** (Prompted by OP's question in comment)

As a matter of fact, the hypothesis $\measuredangle EMF = 60^\circ$ is *unecessary*. The other hypothesis alone implies that $EMF$ is **isosceles** and hence that $AC$ perpendicularly bisects $EF$, which, in turn, yields $AE \cong AF$.

Comment: Why all the problem is solved if we show that the triangle is equilateral?

Comment: @IonelaBuciu $AC$ bisects $EF$ by hp, but what we proved implies that it must **perpendicularly** bisects it. Why? Can you proceed from here? Let me know.

Comment: I dont understand why $AC$ bisects $EF$....can you please explain me? Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @IonelaBuciu no problem at all: $AC$ bisects $BD$, and $BD\parallel EF$.

Comment: @dfnh Oooooo...I understand now. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: @IonelaBuciu, as you see it is really important that you put your own effort into the problem. It is not only a matter of "policies"... Look also into my edit. Condition on $\measuredangle EMF$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

$2EF=BD=AC$ (midpoint theorem)

$EF^2=ME^2+MF^2-2\times ME\times MF \times \cos60^{\circ}$ (Cosine Theorem)

$EF^2=ME^2+MF^2- ME\times MF  $

$ME^2+MF^2- 2\times ME \times MF=0$ $(AC=2EF, AC^2=4\times EF^2=4\times ME\times MF$ and $EF^2=ME\times MF)$

$(ME-MF)^2=0$

$ME=MF$

$\triangle AME\cong \triangle AMF$ (SSS congruency)

$\angle EAM=\angle FAM=45^{\circ}$

$\therefore\ ABCD$ is a square.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Can I ask you why the two traingles are congruent?

Comment: I believe you can prove that $ABCD$ is a square without any information on $\measuredangle EMF$, by the way.